# How to get the row index of gridview when a textbox in that row gets focus

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi I have a gridview wherein I have added textbox dynamically as shown in the code below:

```
protected void getDateControls()
{
    foreach (GridViewRow grow in gdView.Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 7; i <= gdView.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            string txtName = gdView.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Text;
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox txt = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
            txt.ID = txtName;
            txt.Width = 25;
            txt.Font.Size = 9;
            txt.Style.Add("text-align", "Center");
            txt.BackColor = Color.Black;
            txt.ForeColor = Color.White;
            txt.BorderStyle = System.Web.UI.WebControls.BorderStyle.None;
            txt.AutoPostBack = true;
            txt.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtName_Changed);
            grow.Cells[i].Controls.Add(txt);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have to get the row index when any of these textbox gets focus. Can anyone help me complete the following code. I want to take the row index in a textbox(TextBox1) which is added to the page during design time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on("focus", "input[id*='txtName']", function() {
            ////help required to get the row index....
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am not sure whether this is the right approach.

Thanking you all in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding an attribute to the TextBox and getting it in the javascript function. So first change the `foreach` in order to add the row number.

```
int rowNumber = 0;

foreach (GridViewRow grow in GridView1.Rows)
{
    for (int i = 7; i <= GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        //rest of code

        txt.Attributes.Add("rowNumber", rowNumber.ToString());     
    }

    rowNumber++;
}
```

And then the javascript function. You may need to adjust it to your exact specifications.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> input[type="text"]').focus(function () {
            var rowNumber = $(this).attr("rowNumber");
            alert(rowNumber);
        });
    });
</script>
```